Screen Time API DeviceReportActivity View Height Doesn't Fit It's Content
everyone
I'm writing an app that uses DeviceReportActivity to show the app usage of users. I followed Apple's Device Report Activity Documentation
and followed the WWDC videos but it's not enough to help me fix it.
If I put a fixed height size, let's say .frame(height: 1000), it works. But if I leave the view to calculate its size based on the content, it does not work.
This is my TotalReportActivityView:
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 5) {
                ForEach(configuration.totalUsageByCategory.filter { $0.totalAppUsage > 60 }) { appContent in
                    HStack {
                        Label(appContent.token)
                            .imageScale(.medium)
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                            .scaleEffect(1.5)
                        
                        
                        Text(appContent.name)
                            .font(ZFont.default)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text(self.formatter.string(from: appContent.totalAppUsage) ?? "No data")
                            .font(ZFont.default)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color(hex: "#7E7B93"))
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                    .padding(.vertical, 4)
                    .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
                }
            }
}

And this is where I call this view in the main App
DeviceActivityReportView()
    .frame(height: 800)

But I don't want a fixed size, I want the view on the app extension to know its size based on the number of configuration.totalUsageByCategory and fit. Do anyone had a similar issue?
Thank you!

facing the same issue
